# brew link jpeg issues

Tags: osx-lion, symbolic-link, jpeg, homebrew, opencv

I am trying to install `opencv` on Mac OSX Lion.

`brew install opencv`

I get the following error (and a few other similar ones)

```
Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link jpeg'
```

When I do

```
brew link jpeg
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d... ln: wrjpgcom: File exists
```

I do not understand what this means? What should I be doing? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with opencv: it's just the jpeg dependency.

ln was asked to create a hard link (which should be `/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/wrjpgcom` -> `/usr/local/bin/wrjpgcom`) but there is already a file at that location.

This doesn't normally happen so I suspect you might have some detritus left behind from a previous recipe version. I would start by getting your brew install closer to the main public version:

```
brew update
brew uninstall jpeg
brew cleanup
```

At this point neither /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg nor /usr/local/bin/wrjpgcom should exist. After verifying that's the case, I'd try repeating the process:

```
brew install jpeg
```

If that works, you should be clear to continue installing opencv.